# Anchor tag for close button at image not working in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a close tag for an image which is working 100% ok with all other browser except Safari following is the exact code.

```
<div id="click" style="position: absolute; bottom: px; right: 9px; top: 2px; z-index: 201">
<div>
<a onclick="document.AdCheckClick1();" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_self">
    <img border="0" src="lhttp://www3.boago.com/SellBranch/Boomerang/se/close.png">
</a>
</div>
```

Can any one please guide me what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

If it works in other browsers except Safari, try using `button` instead:

```
<button onclick="document.AdCheckClick1();" type="button" class="close-btn">
  <img border="0" src="http://www3.boago.com/SellBranch/Boomerang/se/close.png">
</button>`
```

And the CSS:

```
.close-btn {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```